# active-win package not showing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-10

I tried to implement the code below on VS Code on Windows 10. using node js to get meta about the active window but it seems not working. There was no error spit out on the `console.log` at all. The program just exits node.

```
const activeWin = require('active-win');
(async () => {
  console.log(await activeWin());
})();
```

Can anybody tell me how to get the meta using this `active-win` package in Node.js?